# Find all view - viewmodel bindings

Tags: xaml, mvvm, view, binding, viewmodel

Currently the way I find what a XAML view binds to is click on the XAML diagnostics tool (little black bar on top of screen) -> select the control -> see it's properties in code -> see "DataContext" property.

This way you can find what viewmodel binds to what view, however it's a really slow process.

I'm looking for a way to find all currently bound *view - viewmodel pairs*. That would obviously work only in runtime, but that's fine. 
A piece of code, a nuget extension or anything will do that would give me a list of bindings. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I thinks reflection can bring you a long way.

Use the this method to iterate over the files in your output directory. And find all Assemblies

```
Directory.GetFiles()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

Then load the assemblies and look for the right classes.

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Sample.Assembly.dll");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx

Use the TypeDescriptor to get closer information

```
ICustomTypeDescriptor typeDescriptor = dataContext as ICustomTypeDescriptor;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx

and find out the underlying type.

This could be the steps from the top of my head. 
Since powershell can also access dotnet classes this could be a script that outputs the required information and could also be executed within VisualStudio.

BUT... you could also introduce some conventions. The majority of projects I have seen have the same naming pattern. `CustomerView` -> `CustomerViewModel`. This would also apply for components `OrderTableRowView` -> `OrderTableRowViewModel`. With this you would always know which `ViewModel` belongs to which view (or part of the view).

By the way: If you have such a complex structure and so many `Views` and `ViewModels` it could be time to think about something like a Service that pairs Views and ViewModels. Sometimes called `ViewModelLocatorService`. This keeps the mariage between View and ViewModels centralized.

HTH ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help good sir, I'll have the opportunity to look at this on Monday, but it does look like something I could use! :)

Comment: Hello! I found a somewhat simpler way of doing this, although it's still not a 100% solution.

`foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(window.GetType() + "=>" + window.DataContext);
                };`

...does the job, however it doesn't get the child element of each window. I'm currently searching for those within the view (Content - Children?). This needs to be done while you're debugging.
I see that I could also use the WPF visualiser (click the magnifying glass), to find individual datacontexts.

Comment: But WPF visualiser is about the same as the Live Visual Tree, so it's a "sniper gun" solution, rather than a "shotgun".